# Adding points to existing hair curves?

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair, sculpt-mode

is there a way to add vertices to the new hair curves after they've been created either in sculpt mode or with geo nodes? I know you can delete vertices, but I can't seem to figure out how to subdivide/add them in, and it's so hard to find information on hair curves. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New control points can be added using the `Resample Curve` node in geometry nodes. The node has 3 modes. Count, length and evaluated.

Count is the number of points that you will have after resampling. It's an integer field. Larger the value, more the points.

Length is the distance between two points. Lower the distance, more the points.

Evaluated uses a Boolean field to evaluate.

But in order to actually modify these new points you will have to apply the geometry nodes modifier.

Comment: Aha, thank you! I've been pretty much bound to the essentials assets because I'm scared of geometry nodes lol, guess I should put some time into learning them. I also just figured out a hacky way to subdivide the curves with the assets from 3.5: add in a curl modifier, turn off existing guide map and turn down guide distance and radius to 0, then set desired subdiv level. Apply that, and it'll subdivide the curves without changing them, then you can add the smooth curves asset if you want.